# Register a New User when using JWT strategy

Tags: node.js, jwt

I am trying to use `passport-local-mongoose` for registering my user with `passport-jwt` strategy for authentication on `login` route. I am not able to register my user and instead, getting back a `MissingPasswordError` on Postman.

Here is my code

```js
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const User = require('../models/user');

router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('jwt', { session: false }), (req, res) => {
    res.header({
        status: '200',
        'Content-Type': 'Application/Json',
    });
    res.json({
        'status': 'ok',
        'message': `You have successfully logged in, ${req.user.username} !`
    })
});

router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    const username = req.body.username;
    try {
        // here i am getting an error since password is not going through. 
        const user = await User.register(new User({ username }, req.body.password))
        if (req.body.email) {
            user.email = req.body.email;
        }
        const savedUser = await user.save();
        console.log(savedUser);
        res.json({
            status: 200,
            'Content-Type': 'Application/Json',
            'message': `You have successfully regirstered yourself, ${savedUser.username}!`
        })
    } catch (err) {
        err.statusCode = 500;
        res.header({
            status: '200',
            'Content-Type': 'Application/Json',
        });
        res.json({ err });
    }
});

module.exports = router;
```

I am also trying to use `async/await` instead of callbacks. The original syntax of `register` method is :-

```
User.register({username:'username'}, 'password', function(err, user) {
   ...
});
```

I have a few questions :-

- What's causing this problem ?
- Is my way of using `async\await` incorrect ? What's the correct way to use `async\wait' here ?
- Is it incorrect to `passport-local-mongoose`'s `register` method to register my User while I'm using `passport-jwt` strategy for authentication ?
- What's the correct way of solving this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to this problem. I don't clearly understand why but I think the problem lies with using `register` method since the `register` method is provided by `passport-local-mongoose` which actually uses and implements a `passport-local` strategy internally.

Meanwhile, the strategy being used here is `passport-jwt`. I browsed the internet to gather info on how to *register* a new user when implementing `passport-jwt` strategy. Below is the solution that I got and what actually worked for me :-

1. First we will uninstall some unwanted packages and install some new ones.

   ```
   npm uninstall passport-local passport-local-mongoose
   npm i bcryptjs
   ```

**NOTE**: The first command is not necessary but I wanted to get rid of unwanted packages.

2. Use `bcryptjs` to manually generate `salt` and a `hash` and then store them to database. You can learn more about `bcryptjs` from its documentation. [bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs)

   ```
   const bcrypt = require('bryptjs');
   ```

Then inside the `/register` route,

```
router.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
        const password = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, salt);
        const user;
        user.username = req.body.username;
        user.password = password;
        if (req.body.email) {
            user.email = req.body.email;
        }
        const savedUser = await user.save();
        console.log(savedUser);
        res.json({
            status: 200,
            'Content-Type': 'Application/Json',
            'message': `You have successfully regirstered yourself, ${savedUser.username}!`
        })
    } catch (err) {
        err.statusCode = 500;
        res.header({
            status: '200',
            'Content-Type': 'Application/Json',
        });
        res.json({ err });
    }
});
```

**NOTE**: The original documentation [brcypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs) uses `callbacks` but I have implemented using `async/await`.Install latest version to avoid any errors.